# AdMob app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, crash, admob, adview

My Code:
Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(adView!=null) adView.destroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices = "MY_TEST_DEVICE"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="...."
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com....MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It just keeps crashing on my testing device in this line:  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
The App isnt published in the Play Store, because i want to test it first.
So the error should be in the xml. I hope you can help me.

EDIT: logcat:

```
06-19 19:47:25.968  19697-19697/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL     EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-19 19:47:54.379  20244-20244/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-19 19:49:34.906  20657-20657/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-19 19:50:20.925  21220-21220/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class   "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.stefan.game-2.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    ... 15 more
    06-19 19:52:36.770  22087-22087/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.stefan.game-1.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    ... 15 more
    06-19 20:02:56.041  23603-23603/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/AdView
    at com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.stefan.game-2.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    ... 15 more
    06-19 20:04:33.134  24855-24855/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/AdView
```

EDIT 2: I got it working by reading this: [Android Studio - Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649586/android-studio-error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview) and doing gradlew clean in terminal and clicking Build -> Rebuild Project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: Where can i see the logcat? Im using Android Studio

Comment: the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView looks like I dont have the right library, but i added the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar

Comment: Did you create a libs/folder in your project ?

Comment: it was already there and I added the GoogleAdMob.....jar

Comment: May this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: thx but I'm pretty sure, the Library is added

Comment: I got it working by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649586/android-studio-error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview and doing gradlew clean in terminal and clicking Build -> Rebuild Project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by reading this: [Android Studio - Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649586/android-studio-error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview) and doing "gradlew clean" in terminal and clicking Build -> Rebuild Project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the googleadmob.jar in your project... download it from admob site and and extract the googleAdmobAdsSdk.jar from it.. copy it into your libs folder of project

now Right Click on project ->Build Path->java Build Path->libraries 
check if the jar is imported and if not than click on add jar and add it from libs folder

NOW check the Order and Export tab and make sure that there is tick on that jar

click ok

may be this could help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare xmlns:android at the start of LinearLayout

You also need to import the admob code to the library

Comment: What do you mean with "You also need to import the admob code to the library"?

Comment: I already tried to add the AdView in the java code but it crashed there too. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you add the JAR to the java build path? See link above for instructions

Comment: "Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.stefan.game.MainActivity.onCreate" and "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView" looks like its a problem with the library

Comment: Im using Android Studio and there it is a little bit different. I copied the Library to the libs folder and then I right clicked it and clicked add to library.

Comment: Sorry I have never used Android Studio

Comment: no problem it still crash after changing the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-... to GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.jar

Comment: I had the same problems a few months ago where i was using eclipse with adt plugin

Comment: I got it working by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649586/android-studio-error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview and doing gradlew clean in terminal and clicking Build -> Rebuild Project. Thanks for the help!