# Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView in Android Studio

Tags: admob, android-studio

I have the same exact issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523703/2512284), only I am not working in Eclipse, I'm working in Android Studio.
There doesn't seem to be an option to Order and Export my SDK jar, unless I'm missing it.
Is there any parallel option?

I have included the SDK in my libs/ folder, andI have also verified that my build.gradle includes

- compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17069196/2512284).

Comment: Could you include your build.gradle contents and the contents of the xml layout file that has your adview in it?