# Android Studio: link to external module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio 1.0.1, loving it so far. The only issue that I have is I would like to make my project depend on an external module. If I add a module to my project, the entire module source gets copied. This obviously jeopardise the very concept of library.

Reading around, one of the recurring tips is to add to `settings.gradle` something like

```
include ':module1'
project(':module1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project B/Module 1')
```

and then, in `build.gradle`

```
compile project(':module1')
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work on AS 1.0.1. Other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588389/android-libraries-in-android-studio) collected slightly different approaches, but they all seem to be updated.

Is there anything new under the sun for AS 1.0.1 ?

Comment: That's the right approach. What's not working about it?

Comment: When compiling the main project, I keep getting the error `Gradle 'module1' project refresh failed. 'Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.` When I build module1 by itself it succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means it's not finding a **build.gradle** file at the place where it's looking for it, which is in this case the `../Project B/Module 1` directory.

If Project B is a multi-module project, meaning that it has a top-level **build.gradle** file that doesn't have an `apply plugin` statement, but it does have a **settings.gradle** that refers to a submodule, try pointing directly to the submodule in the project you're linking to **Project B**.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I pointed indeed to the submodule! I then got the error `Error:Dependency myProject:module1:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency.`, to fix which I changed the included module into a library.

Comment: It seems like adding the apply-plugin helps.